# in term-mode, how do I run regular emacs commands?

Tags: term

Upon starting term-mode, Emacs delegates all keypresses to the terminal you're running.

That's great for compatibility purposes, but leaves Emacs functionality behind. How do I get back to Emacs features (for example, to switch a buffer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In term-mode, there are [two input modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html). In the default input mode -- `char-mode` -- all keypresses (except `C-c`) are sent to the terminal to do what it wishes with.

If you change the input mode to `line-mode`, then regular Emacs commands work. You can switch to `line-mode` with `C-c C-j`. You can switch back to `char-mode` with `C-c C-k`.

Comment: Note that there is also `term-escape-char` (defaults to `C-c`). This keypress is not sent to the terminal directly even in `char-mode`, but is translated to `C-x`. With its help you can switch from a `char-mode` term buffer to a different window using `C-c o` (translated to `C-x o`), to a different buffer with `C-c b` (`C-x b`), get a list of buffers with `C-c C-b` (`C-x C-b`), etc.

Comment: How can I make line-mode the default ?

Comment: @haknick I'm not sure offhand -- you should ask a separate question about that, and see if anyone knows.

Comment: Unfortunately, the commands that I'd want to use most often in a terminal window aren't on C-x : those related to marking (C-space and so on) and scrolling (pgup / pgdown). Having to switch to line mode and back for these would be absurdly laborious. Looks like for term to be useful for running a shell one would need some intermediate layer like screen -- in which case there is little point.