# In term-mode how can I make line-mode the default

Tags: term

Got line-mode to work as for this: [in term-mode, how do I run regular emacs commands?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5690/in-term-mode-how-do-i-run-regular-emacs-commands/5691?noredirect=1#comment25688_5691)

Now how do I make it the default ?

Comment: I don't use that library, but how about?:  `(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'term-line-mode)`  Either evaluate that statement after adding it to your `.emacs` file or restart Emacs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [term.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term.el#n1364) it seems char mode is enabled right after running `term-mode` (and hence `term-mode-hook`) as such enabling `term-line-mode` in `term-mode-hook` would not work. The only option I can think of is advicing the function `term` and `ansi-term`, like so

```el
(defun my-enable-term-line-mode (&rest ignored)
  (term-line-mode))

(advice-add 'ansi-term :after #'my-enable-term-line-mode)
(advice-add 'term :after #'my-enable-term-line-mode)
```

However you loose all the goodness of `term` in line mode, if you are looking for line-mode behaviour I think you will be better served by `shell` (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`<kbd>RET</kbd>) or even better `eshell`.

Comment: This is wonderful. From here, I'm able to switch between line-mode and char-mode using `C-x C-j` and `C-x C-k`.